# Compare two binary array with a threshold(approximate matching)

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, pattern-matching, string-matching

I've two binary arrays, one with size 34(pattern) and another with size 10000(target).
 I want to see if there is any pattern in target with a threshold (e.g at most 4 mismatching) 
 and return number of matches (no overlay occurs, if one match then next match will be 800 cell far away).
 I know it is a type of approximate matching problem but I don't know what algorithm to use which has the best performance. what I've done till now: (method like2 has better performance)

```
void compare (bool *target, int t, bool * pattern , int p , int threshold)
{
    for(int i =0;i<t-p;i++){
        if(like(target+i,pattern,p,threshold)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void like2(bool *target, bool * pattern , int p , int threshold){
    int k =0;
    for(int i =0;i<p, ;i++){
        k+= target[i] ^ pattern [i];
    }
    return (k<=threshold);
}
void like(bool *target, bool * pattern , int p , int threshold){
    int k =threshold;
    for(int i =0;i<p,k>=0 ;i++){
        if(target[i]!=pattern[i]){
            --k;
        }
    }
    return (k >=0);
}
```

I've tried to use string matching algorithms such as Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm but they are exact matching and changing them to approximate matching algorithm is a hard way.

Comment: Add early return when `k` is already over threshold

Comment: it does not increase performance so much!

Comment: @abdolahS What do you mean if there is a (near) match then the next match will be at least 800 "cell" away? Are you greedily searching from left to right for (near) matches in the big string, and then if you find one then you move 800 places to the right in the big string to look for the next near match?

Comment: @abdolahS Also do you mean you want the string of 34 bits to match a substring of the 10000 bits with at most 4 mismatching bits, or at least 4 matching bits? This makes a big difference. Near matches (number of mismatched bits is small) are easier to deal with than very loose matches (number of mismatched bits is potentially large).

Comment: @user2566092 , yes for both questions, and also I search for a substring with at most 4 mismatching bits.

Comment: I met exactly the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

Combine the pattern into (long) integer `pattern_int` as it is only 34 bits. Now loop through `target`. At `k = 0` you combine `target` bits 0–33 as for the pattern, to `combined_int`. When you get to the `k + 1` recompute `combined_int` as follows:

```
combined_int = (combined_int << 1) & ~(1 << 34) | target[k + 34];
```

Basically, you shift it by one position (since you advance from `k` to `k + 1`), clear out the no-longer-there bit and add one new.

To see if match is "close enough" to pattern, XOR `combined_int` with `pattern_int` and count number of 1 bits. I believe the latter is done in single instruction on modern CPUs.

**EDIT**: When you build initial combination, make sure that `pattern[0]` ends up as the most significant bit in `pattern_int`, and likewise for `target`. Otherwise you need to change the way `combined_int` is recomputed accordingly.

Comment: thanks, it's a nice answer, but what about the situation where pattern length is more than long bit length?(e.g 100 bit instead of 34?)

Comment: You could generalize it by making `combined_int` and `pattern_int` several ints (or an array of ints) and shift one bit from lower ints into higher. However, performance would also decrease, though for two ints (100 bits) it should still be better than compare-by-elements solution, I'd guess. But in general this doesn't scale up too well, yeah. It would generally depend on expected size of inner loop of compare-by-elements. Overall, the larger threshold to pattern size ratio, the better is the bitwise algorithm I described.

Comment: @abdolahS - there are a few 128-bit registers, if that works for you.